# how to force a new line

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to force a new line in between message and the hideemail()

the following does not work

`document.write(message);document.write /n; hideemail();`

whats my best or easiest way to go about this

Comment: Line break in HTML is [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br). Try `document.write('<br>');`

Answer (score 0):

As Vitalii pointed out you need to use the html tag equivelant of `\n` which is [`br`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

```js
document.write('ffff');
document.write('<br>');
document.write('dddd');
document.write('xxxx');
```